# Doxygen upset by a symbol defined in more than one C header

Tags: c, doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

Using Doxygen 1.8.7, soon to be upgraded to 1.8.17.

I'm editing documentation in a C library which declares the same symbol in three different headers. The three declarations have doc comments that put the symbol in three different groups with different descriptions. C is fine with this, as long as no two of the three headers are used together. Doxygen considers it a multiple declaration, issues three warnings, and ignores two of the definitions.

What's the best way to deal with this?

The only solution I've found is the #ifndef/#endif trick described in https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_code. This would let me stuff all three symbol descriptions into one symbol declaration's Doxygen comment and tell Doxygen to ignore the other two. But the description will appear in only one group, which will be the right group for only one of the three declarations.

To illustrate the problem, header file aaa.h has a declaration like this:

```
/**
 * This little piggy goes to market.
 */
#define PIGGY 3.1415926
```

Header file bbb.h has this:

```
/**
 * This little piggy stays home.
 */
#define PIGGY 0.0
```

And header file ccc.h has this:

```
/**
 * This little piggy eats roast beef, or is a vegetarian and doesn't eat
 * beef at all.
 */
#define PIGGY -1.0
```

Is there a better way?

Telling the engineer to clean up the code is not a solution. I'm in a working culture where engineers are very unlikely to change code on an editor's request. We're too late in the release cycle for them to do that even if they agree.

Comment: Why upgrading to only 1.8.17 and not to the current released version (1.9.1) ? Furthermore show some code you have that illustrates the problem.

Comment: "defines the same symbol in three different headers" is a problem of its own. I hope you mean "declares the same symbol in three different headers". Even "defines a symbol in a header" I would attack. I got that you cannot clean up the code. This is about clarity of your question. Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: @Yunnosch Could be `#define`-ed?

Comment: @EugeneSh. True. Even plausible, seeing the context with "the #ifndef/#endif trick". But I'd still recommend clarifying. And I'd dislike #defining in more than one header not any less.

Comment: "Declare" rather than "define" is technically correct, and I have changed the description. I also have written an illustration of the problem, although I'm not sure it adds anything to the description. /// I will be upgrading to 1.8.17 because that is the latest version that my organization has tested and qualified for use. We have standards and procedures; I can't just use any version of software I please. The final version of the document will be built with 1.8.17 on a server that I don't even control.

Comment: With the limited information i.e. the 3 files and a default Doxyfile I'm not able to to reproduce your problem. The information goes into 3 separate files and no warnings are emitted (with the 1.8.7 version).

Comment: Amazing that a company with standards and procedures allows this type of code! It looks also that there are multiple targets build in one tree and that there is no good separation between these targets or that the documentation for all targets is squashed into one document.